# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, vk-mini-apps

При попытке написания приложения на VK Mini Apps возникает ошибка `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. Что я пытаюсь сделать:

```js
var panels = this.props.datas.map((data) => 
    <Panel id={data.projectid}>
        <Group title="Информация">
             <Cell>
                  <h1>help me please</h1>
             </Cell>
        </Group>
    </Panel>)
```

В `this.props.datas` хранится массив с данными, `data.projectid` это число например `"949075982"`, вопрос такой, почему происходит эта ошибка, как ее исправить?

Дополнительная информация:
[image: Ошибка из браузера]
Ошибка из инспектора элементов

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at View.js:546
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at View.render (View.js:545)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18483)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18438)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:20173)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:337)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:386)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:439)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:25768)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24682)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:24658)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24247)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23674)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:27092)
    at react-dom.development.js:27517
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:24412)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:27516)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:27596)
    at index.js:28
```

UPD: как мне объяснили на Github,  не хочет принимать массив компонентов, как это исправить я пока что не знаю

Comment: `console.log(panel);`

Comment: @Igor [ссылка на картинку](https://imgur.com/a/fu83zgb)

Comment: Вам нужно найти объект хранящий этот id и понять, почему он пустой.

Answer (score 1):

Если верить официальной документации, то можно узнать:

*Структура должна быть постоянной и не должна меняться в рантайме. То есть нельзя на лету добавлять и удалять Panel или View. Нельзя так же менять id у Panel или View. Структура – это декларация приложения. Единственный способ для перехода между Panel в пределах View и View в пределах Root – это обновление свойств activePanel и activeView соответственно.*

**Всё просто**

Нужно задать жёсткую структуру View->(Panel, Panel) и больше её не менять. VK UI использует id панелей для своих переходов, а попытка изменить id приводит к "исчезновению" ссылок на панели - вот отсюда и ошибка.

**И да я как раз вовремя ответил**